# Why most embed feature doesn't work?

Tags: embed

Someone tried to embed this

https://9gag.com/gag/axzLxBK

In my friends' site here

It fails.

Some links can be embeded though

This link seems to work fine

https://www.unilad.co.uk/technology/app-that-can-undress-women-has-been-taken-offline/

Why some links can be embeded and others cannot?

Comment: This isn't an answer, but these are powered by OEmbed, that's the mechanism behind it

Comment: What is oembed?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/article/embeds/

Answer (score 0):

WordPress relies on the open standard for embedding called OEmbed. This is what makes Youtube URLs turn into video players when copy pasted into a post, etc

By default WordPress only supports a predefined list of OEmbed providers, so it knows how to ask Youtube or Vimeo for an embed snippet, but 9gag isn't in that list.

On further investigation, it doesn't appear that 9gag has an oembed provider. I ran the 9gag URL through an OEmbed tester at https://oembed.frdnspnzr.de/ and it could not find any means of using OEmbed.

If 9gag did support OEmbed ( which it doesn't ), it could be added via a plugin using the API calls, telling WP what a 9gag URL looks like and where to go for the snippet